# Determining whether a sequence is ergodic

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory

Suppose $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb Z}$ is an ergodic sequence (where $X_i$'s are real valued random variables). I want to answer the following question:

1. Is the sequence $(\ldots,X_{-2}+X_{-1}, X_0 + X_1, X_2 + X_3, \ldots)$ also ergodic?

But I know from  Samorodnitsky's "Stochastic Processes and Long Range Dependence" that the following sequence is ergodic:

$(\ldots,X_{-2}+X_{-1}, X_{-1}+X_{0}, X_0 + X_1,  X_1+X_2,  X_2 + X_3, \ldots)$ is ergodic. So question 1. reduces to answering the following question:

2. Is $(X_{2n})_{n \in \mathbb Z}$ ergodic?

My attempts:

I tried considering some examples and in both the (simple) examples I considered, $(X_{2n})_{n \in \mathbb Z}$ also turned out to be ergodic:

Ex1. $X_i$ are iid random variables, then clearly true.

Ex2. $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb Z}$ is a Markov chain which is aperiodic, irreducible and positive recurrent then $(X_{2n})_{n \in \mathbb Z}$ is also a Markov chain having all the above mentioned properties and hence is ergodic.